# Grade category creation

Tags: desire2learn

The Valence API documentation specifies that `Grade Objects` of type `Category` [cannot be created](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/grade.html#id1) through the API, yet later on in the documentation there is a reference to a `POST` action possible on `Grade Categories`.

What's the story here, is there something in the documentation that I'm missing?

http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/grade.html

Answer (score 0):

I believe this means that you shouldn't try to use the [POST route to create a grade object](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/grade.html#post--d2l-api-le-%28version%29-%28orgUnitId%29-grades-) to create a grade category; instead, you must use the [POST route to create a grade category](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/grade.html#post--d2l-api-le-%28version%29-%28orgUnitId%29-grades-categories-) to create a grade category. Grade category objects may be characterized as a special kind of grade object, but you should use the grade category APIs to manipulate them.